# Too slow internet and all ISP censorships are gone when connecting to my wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a strange issue at my place. I am experiencing very slow internet speed recently and same time I could see that all blocked contents from my ISP is unblocked from me.

I first thought it's a problem with ISP end but they said that they don't have any issue at their end and when I connect my laptop directly via cable to their Tilgin Ethernet gateway I don't have any issues. Then I restarted my wireless router (Belkin Play), everything was fine for about 15 minutes – no more slow internet and I couldn't access blocked sites.

15 minutes later same story again – slow internet and no blocked contents. I reset my router, installed firmware back but every time when router restarts for 15–20 minutes everything is fine but after that, same issue.

Therefore I thought my wireless router is the culprit and bought a brand new DLINK 826L router. After installing, for 30 minutes everything was fine but then same issue with this router too. I have installed it at my friends place to see if router is having any issue and it's perfectly fine.

Tried reaching ISP to check if they can see error in their Ethernet gateway but they are saying if connection if fine when connected directly to their gateway they cannot help me.

Comment: It sounds like someone has configured your router to use a VPN for Internet traffic.

Comment: Hi David, If someone else have connected won't I see him in my wlan client list. Also when I have installed the new router my password and ssid also got changed

Comment: I don't think they're connected to your router *now*. I think they configured it at some point in the past.

Comment: IF that is the case is there anything that I can do. I have rest my wireless router and also reinstalled the firmware

Comment: See if your default gateway changes. Maybe there's another machine on your network that's running a DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

If your "block contents" are via a DNS blocking service then there are a few things that could be causing this:

1. You are connecting to someone else's wireless and they do not have the DNS server that does your blocking set up on it.
2. It is possible that your modem's router and your wireless access point are both acting as DHCP servers and the filtering DNS server is not set up on the wireless.

I would double check that you are connecting to your own network as that is more likely the problem, but if it is not you will need to either disable the wireless's DHCP server or set that server up to use the same DNS server as the modem's router uses.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your reply. I'm indeed connected to my home network. Apologies I'm not a network pro so there may be dumb comments from my side. I do not have any access to the Tilgin Ethernet gateway which belongs to my ISP. I will disable my wireless router DHCP server setting (if that what you mean) to see if problem is resolving.

Comment: Hi Scott, No still it's same. To tell you more about these blocked sites, I'm in UAE so almost all adults sites and some sites like thepiratebay is blocked over here by ISP. Somethink like Hotspot shield need to be used to get rid od this censorship. Funny thing is that I do not require any software now as my router is letting me by pass these without any of my interventions. Which is good in a way but the downside is as soon as I'm unblocked my internet speed is affected badly. Though speed test still shows good results.